# Datepicker on iPAD missing 'Done' button

Tags: ios, html, ipad, date, atg

I have a **"date input field"** that uses the default **html5** `Date picker` on a form.

This renders and works well on all supported browsers, but on the iPad using **"Safari"**, there is no '**done**' option showing when selecting the date.

The '**done**' option does appear when using this form on an iPhone however.

The form is built in `ATG`, and is a `jsp`.

The code I am using for the `Date picker` is:

```
<dspel:input id="treatmentDate${fieldCount}" type="date" min="${minDateCal}" max="${maxDateCal}" bean="${fieldBeanStringDate}.stringTreatmentDate" style="width:184px"></dspel:input>
```

Like I said, the above code works fine, it's just the absence of a '**done**' option that is causing some confusion.

Is there any control that would activate this for an iPad?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Trying accessing the W3 Schools example page for `<input type="date" />` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date).

If you encounter the same issue on your ipad then you have probably encountered a bug and the alternative would be use a javascript date picker (using jquery or similar) as workaround/fallback for browsers which do not fully support html5 date pickers.

The article [here](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/30/creating-a-native-html5-datepicker-with-a-fallback-to-jquery-ui/) describes how to do this.

Comment: @dradd Have you tried using the w3c schools example on your ipad which can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date)?  If the issue exists there then this *might* be a bug which you have to workaround.